# Equate a Tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to equate a subarray of a tensor in Tensorflow using the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.zeros(shape=[2,2])
b = tf.placeholder(shape = [1])
a[0,0] = b
```

But there is an error message "'Tensor' object does not support item assignment". I would like to know why.

Answer (score 0):

Tensors in Tensorflow are components to build a computational graph. In Tensorflow the tensors are evaluated in sessions. For your question - my guess is the assignment operator might be ambiguous since it can mean equate by value or by reference (meaning that `a[0,0]` is connected to `b`), which is not ideal. If you want to do calculations with high dimensional tensors/matrices, you can use numpy. Tensorflow is not built for that purpose.

Also, one of the complaints about Tensorflow is that it's not very pythonic. You can look into pytorch to get a more pythonic taste of deep learning.

Comment: But if I change it to b = a[0,0], it works. (Here a is placeholder, b is variable)

Comment: Then a would not be a placeholder anymore, by assigning a[0,0] to b, you discarded the original value/reference of b. b will be a reference of a[0,0] in the sense of computational graph.

Comment: I would suggest you read into deep learning and what are the problems tensowflow is trying to solve, then you will have less confusion about why it behaves this way.

Comment: This is actually a simplified version of my problem. My original problem is A is a tf.placeholder(shape=[2,3,3,1]), now I would like to duplicate the tensor to form a tensor of shape [2,3,3,3]

Comment: I believe I saw that post and commented on it. you can look for the post I referenced in the comment.